# I want to calculate the number of days in a specific period of time when the closing price minus the opening price is greater than 20

Tags: pine-script

I want to calculate the number of days in a specific period of time when the closing price minus the opening price is greater than 20. For example, in the past 100 days, how many days have the closing price minus the opening price been greater than 20?

Answer (score 0):

This will work on a 1D chart:

```
//@version=4
study("")
i_limit = input(20.)
bigBars = sum(close - open > i_limit ? 1 : 0, 100)
plot(bigBars)
```